# Does mobile browser support Three.js application

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, three.js

I have my application which bases on Three.js library. However, it doesn't run on mobile browser when I used WebGLRender. I checked some application from Mr.doob (http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_equirectangular). I wonder whether or not mobile browser support three.js or I missed something to run its application on device?
Tks

Comment: http://caniuse.com/webgl current iOS and Android Browser do not support WebGL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I may get wrong, but I remember that Google Street View is a webgl application. It can be use on most mobile browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [caniusel.com](http://caniuse.com/webgl)

WebGL is completely supported by the following mobile browsers

- Safari on iOS 8
- Blackberry Browser 10
- Opera Mobile 22+

Its partially supported(meaning it may or may not work in some cases) by the following browsers.

- Chrome for Android 35
- Firefox for Android 30

Lastly here is the list of mobile browsers that don't support webGL.

- Opera Mini
- Android Browser
- Blackberry Browser 7
- iOS Safari 7 or less
- IE Mobile 10
- Opera Mobile 11.5 or less

Answer (score 2):

What mobile browser? Chrome and Firefox on Android support WebGL. The native browser doesn't work.

Comment: I use safari, chrome on iOS 5, 6 and 7. But all browsers are crashed when run three.js apps

Comment: iOS WebGL support isn't quite there yet, afaik. iOS 8 should support it though.

Answer (score 2):

Android native browser now supports webGL / Three.js